# API Store - Error : Error while adding subscription for user: <user_name>. Reason: Could not execute Workflow

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When subscribing a WSO2 API to a application in WSO2 API store, following error is popped up.
`Error while adding subscription for user: <user_name>. Reason: Could not execute Workflow`
What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

The API needs to be published using a "publisher" account, not from an admin account in WSO2 API publisher.